# primefaces poll not updating

Tags: primefaces, datalist, polling

In my code, I have an ArrayList of strings that are messages to the administrator of a page. when ever certain actions are taken, a string is added to the arraylist to notify the admin that the action has either been completed successfully, or failed to complete. I am displaying this on the page using a dataList with a poll to update it. Though for some reason my poll does not update the list. My code for the prime faces (primefaces version 3.4.2) portion is:

```
 <h:panelGrid>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{admin.servStatus}" for="rText"/>
                    <p:scrollPanel style="height:100px;">
                        <h:form id="statusForm">
                            <p:dataList id="rText" value="#{adminController.model.statusText}" 
                                        var="results" itemType="square" style="height:100px">
                                #{results}
                                <p:poll interval="1"
                                        update=":statusForm:rText"
                                        listener="#{adminController.model.displayMessages()}"
                                        autoStart="true"
                                        widgetVar="statusPoll"/>
                            </p:dataList>
                        </h:form>
                    </p:scrollPanel>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the name of form from your update poll

like this

```
 <p:poll interval="1" update="rText"
```